# Accessing the "accounts" variables of the local blockchain

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ethers.js, mocha

here's the following code :

```
const Vault =  artifacts.require("Vault");

describe("Write features of vault", function (accounts) {
    it("able to receive money", async function(){
        const vault = await Vault.new();
        const amount = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
        console.log(accounts[0]);
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: vault.address, value: amount});
        assert.equal(await web3.eth.getBalance(vault.address), amount);
        assert.equal(100, 100);
    });
});
```

when I console.log `accounts` , I get `"undefined"`, how can I get to access that variable by only using the syntax `"describe/it"` ? I saw that you can use `"contract"` with truffle, but there's sometimes compatibility issues with it.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: truffle, it's integrated with a stack of tools : mocha, chai and ganache.